# Magento Custom Module Not Showing

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, magento-community

I've Create a **custom module** in `community folder`,this module installed successfully and my module is listed in `system/configuration/advanced` and it's enabled.But Still not showing in admin.

My Code:

***app/etc/modules/Codendot_SocialConnect.xml***

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codendot_SocialConnect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Codendot_SocialConnect>
    </modules>
</config>
```

***app/code/community/CodenDot/SocialConnect/etc/config.xml***

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codendot_SocialConnect>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </Codendot_SocialConnect>
    </modules>
    <default>
        <customer>
            <codendot_socialconnect_google>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
            </codendot_socialconnect_google>
            <codendot_socialconnect_facebook>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
            </codendot_socialconnect_facebook>
            <codendot_socialconnect_twitter>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
            </codendot_socialconnect_twitter>
        </customer>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Codendot_SocialConnect>
                     <files>
                        <default>Codendot_SocialConnect.csv</default>
                     </files>
                </Codendot_SocialConnect>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <codendot_socialconnect>
                    <file>codendot_socialconnect.xml</file>
                </codendot_socialconnect>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <codendot_socialconnect>
                <class>Codendot_SocialConnect_Model</class>
            </codendot_socialconnect>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <codendot_socialconnect>
                <class>Codendot_SocialConnect_Block</class>
            </codendot_socialconnect>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <codendot_socialconnect>
                <class>Codendot_SocialConnect_Helper</class>
            </codendot_socialconnect>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <codendot_socialconnect_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Codendot_SocialConnect</module>
                    <class>Codendot_SocialConnect_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </codendot_socialconnect_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <codendot_socialconnect>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Codendot_SocialConnect</module>
                    <frontName>socialconnect</frontName>
                </args>
            </codendot_socialconnect>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

***app/code/community/CodenDot/SocialConnect/etc/system.xml***

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <customer>
            <groups>
                <codendot_socialconnect_google translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                    <label>Social Connect Google Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <client_id translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Google API Client ID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_id>
                        <client_secret translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Google API Client Secret</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_secret>
                    </fields>
                </codendot_socialconnect_google>
                <codendot_socialconnect_facebook translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                    <label>Social Connect Facebook Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>130</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <client_id translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Facebook App ID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_id>
                        <client_secret translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Facebook App Secret</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_secret>
                    </fields>
                </codendot_socialconnect_facebook>
                <codendot_socialconnect_twitter translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                    <label>Social Connect Twitter Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>140</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <client_id translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Consumer Key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_id>
                        <client_secret translate="label" module="codendot_socialconnect">
                            <label>Consumer Secret</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        </client_secret>
                    </fields>
                </codendot_socialconnect_twitter>
            </groups>
        </customer>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Any suggestion about that please?**

Comment: Can you add your code too it will be better to understand the question.

Comment: @QaisarSatti i've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken in namespace declaration, please update the piece of code bellow 
**app/code/community/CodenDot/SocialConnect/etc/config.xml**

```
<modules>
    <CodenDot_SocialConnect>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </CodenDot_SocialConnect>
</modules>
```

**Edit**

And also:

**/etc/modules/CodenDot_SocialConnect.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CodenDot_SocialConnect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </CodenDot_SocialConnect>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: what meaning? can you explain?

Comment: It's Not working :), same result. in localhost working perfectly but when upload to my server the module not working.

Comment: please, look my update

Answer (score 1):

I think may be something issue with vendor name "**Codendot**".

Some places you write like this "**Codendot**", Only first letter "**C**" is capital.

Some places you write like this "**CodenDot**", Both "**C**" and "**D**" letters are capital.

Please check that and make proper.